# Socket.IO disconnect fires before connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I make clients authorize in chat by sending socket.io message containing their credentials.

What concerns me is that sometimes Socket.IO client trigger disconnect event BEFORE authorization is completed.  This may happen when client send auth message and immediately disconnects.

Since auth message triggers a callback fetching an API, it's always done slower and after 'disconnect' event is triggered thus the app allows someone in chat even though they are already left.

Is there a way in to ensure that 'disconnect' event is fired the last?

```js
 socket.on('authorize', data => {
    
    checkAuth()
    .then(()=> addTochat()) //this resolves after disconnect event is fired
    
 
 })
 
 
  socket.on('disconnect', data => {
  
  removeFromChat()
 
 })
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag after receving `disconnect` event and check that flag in authentication callback before allowing the disconnected user to chat.

This way your app will respect the disconnect event even if it was triggered before.